# Ubuntu Desktop not visible on Azure xrdp

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop

I am trying to set up remote Ubuntu desktop on Azure free tire. I have followed all the steps mentioned in [here](http://markjbrown.com/linux-desktops-in-azure/) and [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-quick-create-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json) Documentation. I have setup instance with resources manager. Setup the rdp. Install xrdp via ssh. Install Ubuntu desktop as well.

Installed -- Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS 
Also installed xfce as mentioned in [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-classic-remote-desktop) Documentation

In-spite of installing everything properly I see dotted screen when I connected remotely. What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Using xfce if you are using Ubuntu version later than Ubuntu 12.04LTS

We can follow those steps to install xrdp:

```
sudo -i
```

1.Install XRDP Package from Ubuntu Repository

```
apt-get install xrdp
```

2.Installing the xfce4 Desktop environment

```
apt-get update
apt-get install xfce4
```

3.Configure xrdp to use xfce desktop environment

```
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
```

4.Restart xrdp service

```
service xrdp restart
```

5.Test your xrdp connection:
We can use `mstsc` to test xrdp connection.

**Note:**
If you use this command `apt-get install xfce4` get this **error message**:

> W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

Please add `ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sda` to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#
ARRAY <ignore> devices=/dev/sda

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
```

More information about xrdp on azure vm, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-use-remote-desktop).

Comment: Just check if it helps?